# TSQL - Select column values from one table to another one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-server-2012

In a select statement (MSSQL 2012) I want to add column values from one table to another one.

It's best explained by this picture:
[image]

I want to add the text **Manager** from the first table to the **Role** of the second already joined table including the names of the Manager column.

As a result there would be two more rows (DeptID 1 and DeptID 2) with role name "Manager" and the "User A" and "User B" in the Member column.

Just like the Role name should always be "Manager" the SubTeamName should always be "Core".

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Base
    (DeptID int, [Manager] varchar(13))
;

INSERT INTO Base
    (DeptID,[Manager])
VALUES
    (1,'User A'),
    (2,'User B'),
    (3,'User C')
;

CREATE TABLE TeamMember
    (ID int,DeptID int,RoleID int, [Member] varchar(57) )
;
INSERT INTO TeamMember
    ([ID],DeptID, RoleID, Member)
VALUES
    (44, 1,2, 'User D'),
    (55, 2,3, 'User E')
;

CREATE TABLE SubTeam
    (ID int, [SubTeamName] varchar(57) )
;

INSERT INTO SubTeam
    ([ID],[SubTeamName])
VALUES
    (44,  'Core'),
    (55,  'Extended')
;

CREATE TABLE Role
    (ID int, SubID int,  [Role] varchar(57))
;
INSERT INTO Role
    (ID, SubID, [Role])
VALUES
    (1,44, 'Sales'),
    (2,44, 'Finance'),
    (3,55,  'Development')
;
```

Current query is:

```
SELECT b.DeptID, t.RoleID, r.Role, t.Member, s.SubTeamName 
FROM SubTeam s
LEFT JOIN Role r ON s.ID = r.SubID
LEFT JOIN TeamMember t ON r.ID = t.RoleID
LEFT JOIN Base b ON t.DeptID = b.DeptID
WHERE b.DeptID is not Null
```

Please also see this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24c43/10)

Maybe I'm thinking too complicated as I tried with Union statement but I believe there is an easier way I hope you can show me.

Comment: Please note it's always best to include the DDL+DML for the sample data in the question directly - links to other websites might be blocked for some users or simply go stale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A union is probably the easiest solution. I've noticed that your current query is a bit too cumbersome - you are using left joins but effectively changing them to inner joins with the condition in your where clause. Also, you are joining the `Base` table but not using it anywhere significant - so I've made a small change to your query.

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT t.DeptID, t.RoleID, r.Role, t.Member, s.SubTeamName 
FROM SubTeam s
JOIN Role r ON s.ID = r.SubID
JOIN TeamMember t ON r.ID = t.RoleID

UNION 

SELECT b.DeptId, NULL, 'Manager', [Manager], 'Core'
FROM Base As b 
JOIN TeamMember As t ON b.DeptId = t.DeptId
```

[See fiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8f0e9/3)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to create my select based on your example.